# Inserting values into a Microsoft Access database using a button on a form

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hi I am currently trying to added a few values inputted in form into my database using the provided line.

```
Private Sub btnInsert_Click()
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Band (BandID, BandName, BandAddress, ContactName, PhoneNumber)"
End Sub
```

I am getting a 3431 runtime error. Where I am messing up here?

Comment: What is the error, after you Googled it? What research have you done regarding the format of an INSERT statement?

Comment: i have looked at other stackoverflow post and have found that the error is most likely located somewhere with in the DoCmd.RunSQL section the problem is that this is syntex focused and I am still trying to leave the syntax...

Comment: No, that's not it. Your problem is not the RunSQL. Well, it's not in the Access code anyway.

Comment: I have checked and all the variable names are correct. Does the order of them matter?

Comment: If BandID is 'auto', that should not be included.

Comment: Why not using a bound form? Inputting the data in a form and adding those data using an INSERT statement doesn't seem quite logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to include auto increment fields. But you to specify fields if you are not inserting every field value.

```
INSERT INTO Band (fieldName1, fieldName2, fieldName3)
VALUES (1, 'DEF', 'ABC')
```

Alternative:

```
sql ="INSERT INTO Band (fieldName1, fieldName2, fieldName3) " & _
"VALUES (1, 'DEF', 'ABC') " & _
"
currentDb.execute sql
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the term 'Values'.

If you include all fields:

```
INSERT INTO Band Values BandID, BandName, BandAddress, ContactName, PhoneNumber
```

If you're not adding all fields, specify the fields first

```
INSERT INTO Band (BandID, BandName, BandAddress)
VALUES (1, 'blah', 'blahblah')
```

I don't think you have to add the ID field if it's an auto-increment id.

Answer (score 0):

In Access, a form is best bound to the table - and then there is no append query needed. When you input it into the form it is going into the table.

If there is a real compelling reason to have an unbound form - then things are more complicated and you must first establish these values in a Select Query so they exist as a record set; then use that as the starting point for your Append query....but like I said - this generally is not the way to go.....